# How to run a powershell script (.ps1) file in Docker

Tags: .net, docker, powershell, cmd, devops

I'm having trouble finding a way to run this in Docker. This is an example of what I'm trying to do with the names changed. This should run a .exe file and input the parameter /URL:https://google.com and other parameters as well. I was trying to run this as a .ps1 file in Docker and run it using CMD.

CMD ["pwsh", "-File", "pwsh_file.ps1"]

Where pwsh_file is:

```
Write-Host Powershell Active...
./folder/file.exe /URL:https://google.com /FIZZ:BUZZ
Write-Host Powershell Complete.
```

Can anyone help me understand where I might have gone wrong here? This set up outputs the Write-Host statements, but it goes over the .folder/file.exe statement as if it never executed. This is the output.

```
Powershell Active...
Powershell Complete.
```

Some other notes are this is a file that uses .net. It also uses .dll files. What I'm most confused about that it does not even return an error message. If you run the .exe file alone, it will open a terminal asking for parameters. If you run it the way I specified, it should just connect to a website automatically.

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `./folder/file.exe /URL:https://google.com /FIZZ:BUZZ` to `Write-Host $(./folder/file.exe /URL:https://google.com /FIZZ:BUZZ 2>&1)`

Comment: That change writes out a blank line. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Sounds like the executable behaves differently than what you're expecting. You can test whether it exited with an error code by inspecting `$LastExitCode` immediately after running it.

Comment: Thanks, now it says "1". Then it is failing with exit code 1.

Comment: Do you have any insight on what that might mean? I'm searching it now.

Comment: Instead of `file.exe` you can test another executable. If finally you know only `file.exe` behaves differently, then the culprit is clear.

Comment: It is the .exe file. I am just not sure how to handle the situation. For instance, when I run the file.exe, it will open a new terminal that will ask for parameters. I'm not sure if that is causing problems with Docker. Although, if you copy and paste the command I wrote from before
```/folder/file.exe /URL:https://google.com /FIZZ:BUZZ```

It will do it's job correctly without error. Any idea why that might be happening?